# Juntar <label> e <input> en formulario

Tags: html, css

Tengo un formulario con una serie de labels e inputs. Con css le he dado algo de forma pero no consigo juntar un poco las etiquetas con los campos de texto. He probado reduciendo el witdh pero se desordena todo.

**EDIT 1**

El fichero CSS:

```
    /* -- General -- */

.header h1 {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 100px;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px 2px black;
    color: white;
    font-size: 3.5em;
}

.menu-index {
    text-align: center;
}

.menu-option {
    padding: 25px;
    margin: 0px;
    border: 1px solid steelblue;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.menu-search {
    padding: 25px;
    border: 1px solid steelblue;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.menu-create {
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid steelblue;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 30px;
}

.table-create {
    vertical-align: center;
    padding: 5px;
}

tr:hover{
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
}

/* -- Forms -- */

.form_constumer ul{
    list-style-type: none;
    list-style-position: outside;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

.form_constumer li{
    padding: 3px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
    position: relative;
}

.form_constumer label{
    float: left;
    padding: 1px;
    margin: 5px;
    margin-top: 3px;
    width: 150px;
}

.form_constumer input{
    padding: 2px;
    width: 400px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px #ccc, 0 10px 15px #eee inset;
}

.form_constumer textarea{
    padding: 2px;
    width: 400px;
    height: 75px;
    border-radius: 2px;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px #ccc, 0 10px 15px #eee inset;
}

.submit {
    background-color: #68b12f;
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#68b12f), to(#50911e));
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #68b12f, #50911e);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #68b12f, #50911e);
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #68b12f, #50911e);
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #68b12f, #50911e);
    background: linear-gradient(top, #68b12f, #50911e);
    border: 1px solid #509111;
    padding-top: 5px;
    margin-top: 5px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #5b992b;
    border-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    -ms-border-radius: 3px;
    -o-border-radius: 3px;
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 0 #9fd574;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 #9fd574 inset;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 #9fd574 inset;
    -ms-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 #9fd574 inset;
    -o-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 #9fd574 inset;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 6px 20px;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: 0 -1px 0 #396715;
}
```

**EDIT 2**

Incluyo el body del formulario:

```
<body>
        <div class="container">
            <header class="header">
                <h1>Gestión Clientes <small>NNNN</small></h1>
            </header>
        </div>
        <div class="container menu-create">
            <form action="crearcliente.php" method="POST">
                <div class="form_constumer">
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <label>Nombre</label>
                            <input type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre" placeholder="Nombre clienta" required>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <label>Apellidos</label>
                            <input type="text" name="apellidos" id="apellidos" placeholder="Apellidos clienta" required>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <label>Alias</label>
                            <input type="text" name="alias" id="alias" placeholder="Alias" required>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <label>Teléfono</label>
                            <input type="number" name="telefono" id="telefono" placeholder="123456789" required>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                           <label>Móvil</label>
                           <input type="number" name="movil" id="movil" placeholder="66666666" required>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <label>Email</label>
                            <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="correo@ejemplo.com" required>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <label>Dirección</label>
                            <input type="text" name="direccion" id="direccion" placeholder="Dirección" required>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <label>Población</label>
                            <input type="text" name="poblacion" id="poblacion" placeholder="Población" required>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <label>Provincia</label>
                            <input type="text" name="provincia" id="provincia" placeholder="Provincia" required>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                           <label>Código Postal</label>
                           <input type="number" name="codigopostal" id="codigopostal" placeholder="417.." required>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <label>Tratamiento Capilar</label>
                            <input type="text" name="tratamientocapilar" id="tratamientocapilar" placeholder="Sedoso" required
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <label>Tratamiento Corporal</label>
                            <input type="text" name="tratamientocorporal" id="tratamientocorporal" placeholder="Seco" required>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <label>Observaciones</label>
                            <textarea type="text" cols="40" rows="6" name="observaciones" id="observaciones" placeholder="Datos de interés..." required></textarea>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <input class="submit" type="submit" name="enviar" value="Crear">
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
   </body>
```

Así es como se ve en el navegador (edge, chrome, etc.):

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Alguna idea o sugerencia?

Comment: ¿Tienes referenciada tu hoja de estilos css en el html?

Comment: Prueba a ver si el [este enlace](https://sites.google.com/site/awes0mem4nfiles/Prueba.html?attredirects=0&d=1) te funciona como quieres.

Comment: Sí @Awes0meM4n, lo que no lo he puesto porque lo tengo con un header(). Pero el css está correctamente referenciado.

Comment: en el ejemplo de codepen se ve que estan juntos, diferente a tu imagen en el post

Comment: ¿Pero te funciona el enlace que te envié como tu quieres?

Comment: @Awes0meM4n La hoja de estilos si que la tiene que tener referenciada ya que el botón tiene estilos CSS.

Comment: @Error404 Esta claro que tiene alguna hoja referenciada o algún estilo funcionando, pero podría tener otra o más de una y que por herencia tenga efectos no deseados, por eso quiero saber si el ejemplo que le puse en el enlace le funciona.

Comment: @Awes0meM4n con el ejemplo que me has pasado sigue igual.

Comment: @David Lo que te he pasado es todo en un fichero de texto plano, debería de funcionar a menos que el error lo tengas tú al usarlo ¿Qué navegador usas?

Comment: Con cualquiera, voy a pasar el fichero completo css, porque con tu fichero si veo que estén juntos.

Comment: @Awes0meM4n he añadido el fichero css, en cualquier caso voy a revisar bien tu fichero, a ver donde puede estar el problema, gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu problema es que los elementos de esa `div` heredan este estilo:

```css
.menu-create {
    text-align: center;
}
```

En cuanto cambies eso se te colocarán los elementos como quieres.

La forma más fácil de arreglarlo es añadir a tu CSS lo siguiente:

```css
.form_constumer{
    text-align: left;
}
```

Comment: He hecho lo que me has comentado pero sigue igual.

Comment: @David Prueba [este enlace](https://sites.google.com/site/awes0mem4nfiles/Prueba.html?attredirects=0&d=1). Si te sale bien entonces debes tener un body distinto al que nos pusiste  porque a mi me sale como decías al principio y se puede comprobar como la herencia del `div .menu-create` la pisa esta nueva etiqueta la capa `.form_constumer`.

Comment: Ok, lo miro y te digo, muchas gracias por tu ayuda.

Comment: Ahora queda todo más juntito, pero lo tengo todo en la izquierda, para ponerlo centrado pongo un float: center; en el form_constumer?

Comment: @David para eso tendrías que reducir el tamaño del `.form_constumer` y centrarlo. Puedes hacerlo añadiendo al CSS del `.form_constumer`  `margin: auto; width: 50%;` por ejemplo.

Comment: gracias por todo. Ahora tengo el formulario algo más centrado.

Answer (score 1):

No podemos probarlo porque no tenemos el código HTML, pero lo que debes hacer es poner debajo de cada label-input un elemento con la clase `.clearfix` que tenga las propiedades:

```css
.clearfix {
    clear:both;
    display: block;
}
```

Lo que te ocurre es que, al reducir el ancho del elemento y estar en `float`, te saltan los campos a la siguiente línea y, con el `clearfix`, digamos que separamos los floats anteriores creando una nueva línea.

Resumen, pon los `clearfix` o ajusta los label e inputs para que la suma de ambos ocupen el 100% del ancho del container.

> PD: actualmente con esto basta para los degradados, el resto ya no se usan.
>
> ```css
> background: linear-gradient(top, #68b12f, #50911e);
> ```

Comment: gracias por la respuesta, a la tarde pruebo tu método, e incluiré el código del formulario. Cuando comentas que tengo que incluir un elemento, ¿a qué elemento te refieres?

Comment: He incluido el body donde está el formulario, gracias de nuevo Daniel.

Comment: Despues de cada input habría que añadir un div con la clase clearfix que es la declarada en tu css como te comentaba

Answer (score 0):

Deberias quitar el float que tienen los labels.

```css
.form_constumer label{
    float: left; --Este float hace que todos los labels se alineen sola a la izquierda y se separan de los inputs.
    padding: 1px;
    margin: 5px;
    margin-top: 3px;
    width: 150px;
}
```

Comment: Así se le juntarán en el centro, pero él quiere que esten alineados y pegados a la izquierda. La primera vez que preguntó, antes de editarla, tenía un enlace a un código donde ponía cuál era el resultado final que esperaba, pero lo ha borrado.

Comment: Se ha borrado solo, iba a editarlo pero ya no está. Buscaré una web donde no se vaya el código.

Comment: Con esta opción no se ha solucionado mi problema, siguen sin juntarse.

Comment: Pero y el archivo HTML dónde está?